# Are there any civil towns/places in Dark souls 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've been playing this game since March 28th and I was wondering if there are any civil places in the game, ya'know like where people who don't come over and kill the second the can get close enough, but is there? I've just reached lost basille and just starting there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are NPCs that won't attack you unless you do enough damage to them for them to turn hostile. The only area I think we could call "civil" is the Firekeepers' hut in the beginning of the game and the town of Majula, where most friendly NPCs gather after you encounter them in the wild.

Like in the last game the people/monsters you meet are undead like you, and most of them have gone mad and will attack on sight.

Comment: Thanks, and that really sucks, I was hoping for a town/kingdom where there were a bunch of merchants and other things, sometimes I see myself playing fable from the original xbox days, I. This game, like it's styled after it or something. I wish it was more like fable

Comment: But thanks bro, now I won't be in suspense for the rest of the game, I hate suspension

Comment: You're welcome! Surprising to hear you comparing Dark Souls 2 to Fable, but I can understand the sentiment. The player's view point and basic movement are similar, but when it comes to world design these games are more about wading through the ruins of a civilization and being thrilled when you find even a glint of life amongst the misery.

Comment: Glad to have helped with the suspense. It can really be _killer!!!_ And I hope you can find more ways to alleviate the suspense of the game here on [link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) ;)